# Update in datatable after updating data

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I'm having a problem updating a column in my datatable after an edit.
I use a dialog to edit the data you want. You are saving everything in the database, the problem
Rezide in updating the table, the fields are being updated with the new values,
Only one that is not updating, just a selectOneMenu that is in the dialog.
The field that is not updating is from the Lotação, the rest is working.

My table..

```
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="TituloCorpo">Alterar Impressora</ui:define>
        <ui:define name="Corpo">

            <div align="center">
                <h:form id="form">

                    <!-- BOTÕES QUE GERA RELATÓRIOS EM PDF E CSV -->
                    <div style="width:2958px">

                        <h:commandLink>
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/img/icon_pdf.png" width="35" title="Relatório em PDF"/>
                            <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tab" fileName="impressoras" pageOnly="true"/>
                        </h:commandLink>

                        <h:commandLink>
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/img/icon_csv.png" width="35" title="Relatório em CSV"/>
                            <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="tab" fileName="impressoras" pageOnly="true" />
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </div>

                    <!-- SCRIPT QUE CRIA UMA TABELA -->
                    <p:dataTable id="tab" var="impressora" widgetVar="tab" value="#{impressoraMB.impressoras}" editable="true" reflow="true" style="width:1100px">

                        <p:column id="fabricante" headerText="Fabricante" filterBy="#{impressora.fabricante}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:170px">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{impressora.fabricante}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column id="modelo" headerText="Modelo" filterBy="#{impressora.modelo}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:170px">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{impressora.modelo}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column id="modeloCartucho" headerText="Modelo do Cartucho" filterBy="#{impressora.modeloCartucho}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:180px">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{impressora.modeloCartucho}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column id="patrimonio" headerText="Patrimonio" filterBy="#{impressora.patrimonio}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:120px">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{impressora.patrimonio}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column id="lotacao" headerText="Lotação" filterBy="#{impressora.nome}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:110px">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{impressora.nome}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Alterar" style="width:70px" exportable="false">
                            <p:commandButton update=":formAlterar:panelAlterar" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Alterar" style="height:35px;width:35px"
                            oncomplete="PF('alterarImpre').show()" ajax="true">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{impressora}" target="#{impressoraMB.impressora}"/>
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Remover" style="width:90px" exportable="false">
                            <p:commandButton update=":formExcluir:panelExcluir" oncomplete="PF('excluirImpre').show()" icon="ui-icon-trash"
                            styleClass="btn  btn-small" style="height:35px;width:35px" title="Excluir">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{impressora}" target="#{impressoraMB.impressora}"/>
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:form>
            </div>
            <!-- PAGINA COM A CAIXA DE DIALOGO -->
            <ui:include src="/panel.xhtml"/>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

My dialog..

```
<p:dialog id="editar" header="Altere os dados desejados" widgetVar="alterarImpre" width="600" location="center"
draggable="true" modal="true" responcive="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <h:form id="formAlterar">
        <h6 align="center"><i>*Para abrir o campo de edição, clique em cima do valor</i></h6>
        <br/>
        <h:panelGrid id="panelAlterar" columns="2" cellpadding="5" width="75%">
            <h:outputLabel for="fabricante" value="Fabricante:"/>
            <p:inplace id="fabricante" editor="true" emptyLabel="Me edite">
                <p:inputText value="#{impressoraMB.impressora.fabricante}" required="true" label="text"/>
            </p:inplace>

            <h:outputLabel for="modelo" value="Modelo:"/>
            <p:inplace id="modelo" editor="true" emptyLabel="Me edite">
                <p:inputText value="#{impressoraMB.impressora.modelo}" required="true" label="text"/>
            </p:inplace>

            <h:outputLabel for="modeloCartucho" value="Modelo do Cartucho: "/>
            <p:inplace id="modeloCartucho" editor="true" emptyLabel="Me edite">
                <h:inputText value="#{impressoraMB.impressora.modeloCartucho}" required="true" label="text"/>
            </p:inplace>

            <h:outputLabel for="patrimonio" value="Patrimonio"/>
            <p:inplace id="patrimonio" editor="true" emptyLabel="Me edite">
                <p:inputText value="#{impressoraMB.impressora.patrimonio}" required="true" label="text"/>
            </p:inplace>

            <h:outputLabel for="lotacoes" value="Lotações:"/>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="lotacoes" value="#{impressoraMB.impressora.id_Lotacoes}" effect="fold" required="true"
                immediate="true" style="width:100%">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{lotacoesMB.listLotacoes}" var="item"
                    itemLabel="#{item.nome}" itemValue="#{item.id}"/>
                    <f:ajax execute="@this"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <br/>
        <div align="center">
            <h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:commandButton id="btnAlterar" value="Alterar" action="#{impressoraMB.alterar}" onclick="PF('alterarImpre').hide()"
                    oncomplete="PF('form').hide(); #{impressoraMB.impressora}" ajax="true" process="@form" title="Alterar">
                    <f:ajax execute="@all" render=":form:tab"/>
                    </p:commandButton>

                    <p:commandButton id="btnCancelar" value="Cancelar" onclick="PF('alterarImpre').hide()" title="Cancelar"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

MY Bean..

```
public class ImpressoraMB {

private Impressora impressora;
private ImpressoraDAO dao;
private List<Impressora> impressoras;

public ImpressoraMB() {
    impressora = new Impressora();
    impressoras = new ArrayList<Impressora>();
    dao = new ImpressoraDAO();
}

public List<Impressora> getImpressoras() {
    if (impressoras.size() == 0) {
        impressoras = dao.getImpressoras();
    }
    return impressoras;
}

public void adicionar() {
    dao.adicionar(impressora);
    impressora = new Impressora();
}

public void remover() {
    dao.remover(impressora);
    impressoras.remove(impressora);
    impressora = new Impressora();
}

public void alterar() {
    dao.alterar(impressora);
    impressora = new Impressora();
}

public void showMsgAdicionar() {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Impressora adicionada", "com sucesso!");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().showMessageInDialog(message);
}

public Impressora getImpressora() {
    return impressora;
}
public void setImpressora(Impressora impressora) {
    this.impressora = impressora;
}
```

}

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using <p:selectOneMenu> instead of <h:selectOneMenu>? Since you're using primefaces it is a better way of using the its elements. Then, also change the ajax tag to <p:ajax> and add the process="@form" attribute and update=":form:tab"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it did not work.

Comment: can you post the backing bean code where you update the table? It's weird since it updates the rest of the table and only the lotação column isn't, maybe there's something wrong there. Would you please edit your answer with the backing bean code?

Comment: Yes I can. I'll be posting.

Comment: when you select a value in SelectOneMenu it updates impressora.id_Lotacoes but your DataTable uses impressora.nome, maybe that's what's wrong

Comment: Thank you very much, that's right. I switched the test and it worked.

Comment: É Brasileiro também, agora que fui ver rsrs.

Comment: hahahah, eu ja tinha percebido mas respondi em inglês pra caso alguém esteja com a mesma dúvida que você possa entender :) Postei uma resposta, se vc puder marcar ela como correta vai ajudar quem visualizar sua questão procurando ajuda. Valeu, abração

Comment: Entendi hahaha. Com certeza. Abraço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your dialog you have

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="lotacoes" value="#{impressoraMB.impressora.id_Lotacoes}" effect="fold" 
    required="true" immediate="true" style="width:100%">
```

while your DataTable uses

```
<p:column id="lotacao" headerText="Lotação" filterBy="#{impressora.nome}" 
    filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:110px">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{impressora.nome}"/>
</p:column>
```

If you change the value in one of the two different .xhtml files you should have the expected result

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the update attribute in your command button or in your ajax call.

```
<p:commandButton id="btnAlterar" value="Alterar" action="#{impressoraMB.alterar}" update=":form:tab" onclick="PF('alterarImpre').hide()"
                oncomplete="PF('form').hide(); #{impressoraMB.impressora}" ajax="true" process="@form" title="Alterar">
```

or

```
<f:ajax execute="@all" update=":form:tab" render=":form:tab"/>
```

Make sure that the object is updated in the backed bean

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tested both ways, and it still did not work. It only works when I run the entire page by pressing the F5 key.

Comment: are you sure of the id of the element you want to update. Check with the browser inspector if the id is correct. And be sure that you correctly update the object in the backed bean that is display in the page

Comment: I checked here and the id is the same. And update correctly on Bean.